# Stored procedure Primary key not declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Apologies for what I'm sure is a very basic question.  I'm newly dived into the deep end of sql and learning as I go.

a) In a stored procedure (sql server 2012) if I do not declare one of the return values a primary key, does it create one?  Because in the case I am doing, I had not planned a key in, and none of the fields could be used as one.

b) If I have to set the key, what is the code to do so?  And can I roll into this question how to have a counter increment with each run through the SELECT (because if I have to set a key, I would probably use that)?

**ETA**
I just came across the concept of cursors, from which I take it you don't need to manage a primary field for the system to keep its rows identified.
@L. Klotz, since you offered a way to make a key: if the system has its own key, in what situation would you use a expressly set one?
and to be clear, I would put it like below?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[partsneed] 
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
   ,@PartIDIN varchar(20)=0
   ,@COstatusIN char=0
   ,@QTYneedIN float=0
   ,@DateNeedIN date='1900/1/1'
   ,@QTYhrsIN float=0
```

Comment: Share the code you have written.

Comment: It doesn't create one unless you set one. This adds an autoincrement primary key column to your current table which doesn't have a primary key. Where tablename is should be the name of your table.
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the primary key, but a code example and further explanation would be helpful. You can try something like:

```
SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) id
        ,[name]
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[names]
```

To create a new auto incremented column.

Comment: Sounds like I don't need to create an actual 'key' in the sense I'm used to thinking.  But I appreciate your code since I have another case where I'd like to track the number of rows are being read by SELECT so I can use it to decide to exit a LOOP or not.  Though that also appears to be something I should do differently...

Comment: err, question.  Am I reading that to say that it will increment on change of name?  What if there are several rows with the same name?  Will it add them up or count each distinct name as 1?

Comment: No. it will create a unique ID for each line, the "order by" is just to define the order (in this case by name alphabetically)